# merging XML documents

Tags: xml, merge, document

I need to merge multple XML documents based on paragraph ids as described below. Basically, it is a document synchronization situation, where paragprahs added to the master document need to be added from the secondary documents; paragraphs removed from the master must be removed the secondary documents, and, finally, some attributes (e.g. 'font') on master document paragraph nodes must be duplicated to the secondary doc while some need to be preserved (e.g. 'author').  I have written some rather brute force ugly the code in c# .net, it semi  works (haven't coded attribute handling keep/update logic) but would much prefer an XSLT solution, as it seems like a perfect application for XSLT, but I am an XSLT 'virgin' thrown into a new 'rush' project... Can someone at least get me started on how to merge the 2 docs (i.e. add paragraphs from master to secondary?)

For example

master.xml:

```
<paragraphs>
<paragraph id="intro" font="bold" author="JS">
   <sentences>
         <sentence>Bla bla bla bla</sentence>
         <sentence>More Bla bla bla bla</sentence>
   </sentence> 
</Paragraph>
<paragraph id="main1" font="bold" author="FTG">
   <sentences>
         <sentence>any text here</sentence>
         <sentence>More Bla bla bla bla</sentence>
   </sentence> 
</paragraph>
<paragraph id="main2" font="bold" author="FTG">
   <sentences>
         <sentence>Added to Master Doc</sentence>
   </sentence> 
</Paragraph>
```

and Secondary.Xml

```
<paragraphs>
<paragraph id="intro" font="normal" author="ZZ">
   <sentences>
         <sentence>Bla bla bla bla</sentence>
         <sentence>More Bla bla bla bla</sentence>
   </sentence> 
</paragraph>
<paragraph id="main1" font="normal" author="XYZ">
   <sentences>
         <sentence>main1 has been edited in secondary doc but needs to remain unchanged</sentence>
         <sentence>More Bla bla bla bla</sentence>
   </sentence> 
</paragraph>
<paragraph id="conclusion" font="bold" author="FTG">
   <sentences>
         <sentence>In conclusion.....bla.../sentence>
   </sentence> 
</paragraph>
</paragraphs>
```

Needs to be merged by removing conclusion paragraph from secondary doc, adding main2 doc to secondary from master, applying font attribute from the master to secondary to the paragraphs that match, but keeping the author attribute unchanged on matching paragraphs. Later part (attribute cloining/preserving is a very minor issue).

```
<paragraphs>
<paragraph id="intro" font="bold" author="ZZ">
   <sentences>
         <sentence>Bla bla bla bla</sentence>
         <sentence>More Bla bla bla bla</sentence>
   </sentence> 
</paragraph>
<paragraph id="main1" font="normal" author="FTG">
   <sentences>
         <sentence>main1 has been edited in secondary doc but meeds to remain unchanged</sentence>
         <sentence>More Bla bla bla bla</sentence>
   </sentence> 
</Paragraph>
<paragraph id="main2" font="bold" author="FTG">
   <sentences>
         <sentence>Added to Master Doc</sentence>
   </sentence> 
</Paragraph>
</paragraphs>
```